# how can i update joinned query from datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i have some example codes

in this codes i add a column in my query  (A.TUTAR+2)

but i cant update access mdb when i changed datagridview

a note : I can combine multiple tables and add more columns

````
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

 Dim myDA As OleDbDataAdapter

 Dim myDataSet As DataSet

 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles  
     Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=|DataDirectory|\MYDB.mdb")  ' Use relative path to database file

     Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT  A.*,A.TUTAR+2  FROM CARTH001 A WHERE KAYITNO = 1", con)

     con.Open()
     Dim dt = New DataTable()
     myDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)


     Dim builder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(myDA)

     myDataSet = New DataSet()

     myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "CARTM001")

     DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("CARTM001").DefaultView

     con.Close()

     con = Nothing

 End Sub



 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

   Me.myDA.Update(Me.myDataSet.Tables("CARTM001"))
     Me.myDataSet.Tables("CARTM001").AcceptChanges()
     Me.myDA.Fill(Me.myDataSet.Tables("CARTM001"))

 End Sub

End Class```
````

Comment: There's no need for you to call `AcceptChanges` because it's called implicitly when you call `Update` on the adapter. There are situations where it's required but only if you disable the implicit call or you use a different `DataTable`, e.g. after calling `GetChanges`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a command builder. You need to create the action commands yourself. If you only want to update one table then you only need one data adapter but if you want to update both tables then, because Access only supports one SQL statement per command, you would need two data adapters.

A single data adapter might look like this:

```vb
Dim updateCommand As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = @MyColumn WHERE Id = @Id", myConnection)

updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@MyColumn", OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "MyColumn")
updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", OleDbType.Integer, 0, "Id")

myDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = updateCommand
myDataAdapter.Update(myDataTable)
```

Multiple data adapters might look like this:

```vb
Dim firstUpdateCommand As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE FirstTable SET FirstColumn = @FirstColumn WHERE FirstId = @FirstId", myConnection)

firstUpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstColumn", OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "FirstColumn")
firstUpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstId", OleDbType.Integer, 0, "FirstId")

firstDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = firstUpdateCommand
firstDataAdapter.AcceptChangesOnUpdate = False
firstDataAdapter.Update(myDataTable)

Dim secondUpdateCommand As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE SecondTable SET SecondColumn = @SecondColumn WHERE SecondId = @SecondId", myConnection)

firstUpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@SecondColumn", OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "SecondColumn")
firstUpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@SecondId", OleDbType.Integer, 0, "SecondId")

secondDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = secondUpdateCommand
secondDataAdapter.Update(myDataTable)
```

Note that you must set `AcceptChangesOnUpdate` to `False` on the first data adapter, otherwise the first `Update` call will implicitly call `AcceptChanges` on the `DataTable` and there will be no changes for the second data adapter to save.

Comment: Thanks for your answer But i have more then 20 columns in theese columns 6 columns are joinned columns. Now i'm using codes like your suggestion codes ... So  how can i update and insert my access table when i added rows in my datagridview?

Comment: I have provided an answer that contains all the information you need. I've shown you how to save data from a column in a `DataTable` to a column in a database table. If you know how to do that for one column then you know how to do it for as many columns as you like.